# onclick not firing on first click, sortable list, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to make a list, where each row can go up or down with the press of a button.

I am using the onclick method on the button with 'this' as the parameter.

When page loads it needs a couple of clicks to fire the event.

After that it needs from 1 to 3 clicks.

Why is that?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

    <title>Schedule</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="eXes">
  <div class="eX">
    1
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="eX">
    2
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="eX">
    3
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveUp(el) {
        var selected = el.parentNode;
        var previous = el.parentNode.previousSibling;
        document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, previous);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveDown(el) {
        var selected = el.parentNode;
        var next = el.parentNode.nextSibling;
        document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, next.nextSibling);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIAIQO31H90L

Comment: First of all, thanks for all the responses. The problem is indeed that the white-spaces get treated as textNodes. The simplest and most elegant way I found here [link](http://xahlee.info/js/js_dom_whitespace_nodes.html) to fix it, is to replace the previous/nextSibling with previous/next**Element**Sibling, though I have not tested for browser support yet.  P.S. The Array.prototype.slice.apply method from @Risa__B was a nice new thing to learn for me, even though not exactly relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you console.log el.parentNode.previousSilbing, you will see that you have a 'nextLine' el between each div, so simply remove that will work, but makes html looks ugly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
 <title>Rota Schedule</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="eXes">
  <div id='1' class="eX">
    1
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div><div div id='2'  class="eX">
    2
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div><div div id='3' class="eX">
    3
    <button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
    <button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function moveUp(el) {
    console.log('click',el.parentNode,el.parentNode.previousSibling)
  var selected = el.parentNode;
  var previous = el.parentNode.previousSibling;
  document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, previous);
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function moveDown(el) {
  var selected = el.parentNode;
  var next = el.parentNode.nextSibling;
  document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, next.nextSibling);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the white-space between each of your div's. The browser treats this as a textNode so when you initially move an element up or down you're actually just swapping it with the white space. Once you've clicked up and down 2-3 times you've effectively 'sorted' the white-space to the bottom of the dom stack and then you no longer see the problem.

A quick fix would be to remove the white-space by changing your markup to close and open the div's immediately next to each other, instead of on a new line.

You can read more about white-space here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace_in_the_DOM

Answer (score 0):

previsousSibling and nextSibling return the immediately preceding or following sibling. In your case you have a line return between each

```
...
</ div>
<div class="ex">
...
```

So if you console.log(previous) your result will be a Text instead of the element.

If you do this your problem will be solve

```
<div class="eX">
1
<button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
<button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
</div><div class="eX">
 2
<button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
<button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
</div><div class="eX">
 3
<button class="up" onclick="moveUp(this)">up</button>
<button class="down" onclick="moveDown(this)">down</button>
</div>
```

But this will make your code visibility worst.

What you should do is to use functions to get the good element. In your case you have to replace previsousSibling and nextSibing by

```
function previousElementSibling( elem ) {

do {

    elem = elem.previousSibling;

} while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );

return elem;
}

function nextElementSibling( elem ) {

do {

    elem = elem.nextSibling;

} while ( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 );

return elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following, i'll remove the event onClick in every down or up in your button and i'll use the Arrary.prototype and forEach to select the elements:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.up')).forEach(function (el){
el.addEventListener('click',function(){

 var selected = el.parentNode,
     previous = el.parentNode.previousSibling;
       document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, previous);

});
});
Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.down')).forEach(function (el){
el.addEventListener('click',function(){

var selected = el.parentNode,
    next = el.parentNode.nextSibling;
if(next == undefined){
next =  document.getElementById("eXes").firstChild;
}    document.getElementById("eXes").insertBefore(selected, next.nextSibling);
        
});
});
```

```html
<div id="eXes">
  <div class="eX">
    1
    <button class="up">up</button>
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="eX">
    2
    <button class="up">up</button>
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="eX">
    3
    <button class="up">up</button>
    <button class="down">down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ForEach**

the foreach function execute a callback function once foreach elment in array, visit this link for more information : 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach/)